# How to use Vagrant and Docker-for-Windows on a Hyper-V system?

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

Back in the day, I was using [VirtualBox (VB)](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Vagrant (V)](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to run VMs. Since I installed [docker-for-windows (DfW)](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) and run V, VB complains about [Hyper-V (HV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V).

```
[user@localhost ~]$ vagrant up
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component
ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Although [this link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/) indicates that V supports HV, the above error message is contradictive. Why does VB look incompatible with HV, why V says that it supports HV and how to prevent that HV needs to be disabled in order to use V again.

```
| Product    | Version |
|:-----------|--------:|
| Vagrant    |   2.0.1 |
| VirtualBox |   5.2.4 |
| Windows    |      10 |
```

**Discussion**

[The suggestion to switch Hyper-V on and off](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) is not the preferred solution as it is time consuming.

If it would be possible to run V and DfW on the same system by replacing VB this could be an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confirmed by [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111013/3627607) referencing  [Microsoft technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/118561b9-7155-46e3-a874-6a38b35c67fd/hyperv-disables-vtx-for-other-hypervisors?forum=w8itprogeneral) once Hyper-V is activated it mask the VT-X instructions of the processor to the OS on top of it and windows run like a guest.

Docker for Windows need hyper-V to work, so disabling it is not really an option.

There's no way to have virtual box running on top of Hyper-V and that's quite normal, you should not run an hypervisor within an hypervisor, they'll fight to orchestrate hardware acces.

The best workaround in my opinion is to create hyper-V virtual machine from vagrant with the [hyper-V provider](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/) instead of virtual box machines, this way you can create VM or container on the same session.

Side note, vagrant already have a note about this in the hyper-v provider documentation page (found while searching the link to add above):

> **Warning**: Enabling Hyper-V will cause VirtualBox, VMware, and any other virtualization technology to no longer work. See [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) for an easy way to create a boot entry to boot Windows without Hyper-V enabled, if there will be times you will need other hypervisors.

Answer (score 5):

A few years later this thread is still the first result in Google, but running Docker+Vagrant (**with VirtualBox**) on Windows isn't a challenge anymore. You can easily run them both, as described [here](https://kubut.medium.com/it-is-2021-running-docker-and-vagrant-parallel-on-windows-isnt-impossible-anymore-a8ea7de0536c)

If for some reason you want to use Vagrant with VirtualBox as a provider you should update to VB 6.x - after that, you can run VirtualBox, Vagrant, and Docker at the same time. Just configure your VM to use Hyper-V as Paravirtualization Interface. You can do it by VirtualBox GUI (VM's Settings -> System -> Acceleration -> Paravirtualization Interface) or by using Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # your config (…)
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize [
      "modifyvm", :id,
       " - paravirtprovider", "hyperv"
    ]
  end
  # your config (…)
end
```

This will work not only for Windows Enterprise/Pro/Edu but also for Home Edition (with WSL2 as Docker Backend). This solution shouldn't break your VirtualBox's machine, so you **don't have to switch hypervisorlaunchtype** over and over again.

Comment: Aww, nice one, I totally missed it was still using virtualbox when reading the blog post.I see value for the home edition of Windows where the Hyperv api is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside Vagrant, you could use the old school Legacy 'Docker Toolbox' instead of 'Docker for Windows'. That means Docker will be slow since its running in a Linux VM I believe.
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/
Other than that, yes I have been restarting my computer everything i need HyperV for Docker or remove it when i want vagrant.